# Is possible to specify text in config wrappers for each hint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have the following code:

```
config.wrappers :file, tag: 'div', class: 'control-group', error_class: 'error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.use :placeholder
  b.use :label
  b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls uploader' do |input|
    input.use :input
    input.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'filename' }
    input.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'action' }
    input.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    input.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
  end
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
input.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'action', text: 'choose a file' }
```

or specify the hint in input, something like:

```
<%= o.input :name,
            as: :file,
            wrapper: :file,
            label: 'Brand',
            required: false ,
            hint_<specific>: 'Text...'%>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#i18n
you can set the text for the hints in a separate file

So I think you need a separate file with something like this

```
en:
hints:
  file: 
    thing1: 'hint for thing 1'
    thing2: 'hint for thing 2'
```

Comment: I have more than one hint, how do I specify each other? May has another way to implement it?